# Iterate Through List of Tuples and Add Value to Specific Tuples

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a a list of tuples and want to iterate through values a and b for all TestTups and add a value to each. I don't want to make any changes to the TestFail tuple or the run values.

Here's an extract of the list:

```
tup_list = [TestTup(a=6, b=4, run=3.0), TestTup(a=8, b=4, run=2.7), TestTup(a=1, b=4, run=3), TestTup(a=8, b=9, run=4), TestFail(a=1, b=4, run=1)]
```

Here's the desired result:

```
new_tup_list = [TestTup(a=11, b=5, run=3.0), TestTup(a=13, b=9, run=2.7), TestTup(a=6, b=10, run=3), TestTup(a=13, b=14, run=4), TestFail(a=1, b=4, run=1)]
```

What's the fastest way of doing this in terms of execution time?

Comment: What are TestTup and TestFail?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list by iterating through the old one:

```
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class TestTup(NamedTuple):
...     a: int
...     b: int
...     run: int
...
>>> class TestFail(NamedTuple):
...     a: int
...     b: int
...     run: int
...
>>> tup_list = [TestTup(a=6, b=4, run=3.0), TestTup(a=8, b=4, run=2.7), TestTup(a=1, b=4, run=3), TestTup(a=8, b=9, run=4), TestFail(a=1, b=4, run=1)]
>>> [TestTup(t.a+5, t.b+5, t.run) if isinstance(t, TestTup) else t for t in tup_list]
[TestTup(a=11, b=9, run=3.0), TestTup(a=13, b=9, run=2.7), TestTup(a=6, b=9, run=3), TestTup(a=13, b=14, run=4), TestFail(a=1, b=4, run=1)]
```